# postgres insert into table with select case

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to insert into a table a set of records which will be extracted based on 2 situations:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (pkid, time_created)
SELECT pkid, time_created,
CASE WHEN tgt_time >= src_time THEN tgt_time as time
    WHEN src_time >= tgt_time THEN src_time as time
END
FROM temptable
WHERE time >= '0001-01-01' and time <= '2016-03-01';
```

I'm trying to do a case on when to use either of the 2 columns to filter the date to extract the records.  Is this possible in postgres or maybe tweak the statement to make it work?

Comment: Didnt' feel like trying it out yourself?

Comment: if you can point me to any documentation then that would be great.  Ive been trying also in pgadmin as of this writing.

Comment: In that case my comment was perhaps too hasty but you should have mentioned that and instead of saying not working you can add what errors you get if any and at least show the table structure so that someone else can try it and let you know what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (pkid, src_time_created)
SELECT pkid, src_time_created FROM temptable
WHERE 
CASE WHEN tgt_time >= src_time THEN tgt_time >= '0001-01-01' and tgt_time < '2016-03-01'
ELSE src_time >= '0001-01-01' and src_time < '2016-03-01'
END
```

This worked with a little tweaking on the query.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong count of columns: insert - 2 columns, select - 3 columns. Probably missed time in `insert into table1 (pkid, time_created, time)`